# What type of circuit is responsible for convolution in the classic analog telephone?

Tags: convolution

I'm interested in learning how telephones work, so I did a little bit of reading about signal processing. When I came up with the word convolution, I quickly realized the importance of this term.

To begin with, I want to know how classic analog telephones worked. The apparent simplicity of their design appeals to me.

What kind of circuit was responsible for convoluting the microphone impulses in a classic telephone receiver, so that this signal could be transmitted over wires?.

Comment: Where do you think convolution was used in analog phones?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Convolution is a mathematical abstraction describing how a linear, time-invariant system affects a signal going through it.

Sometimes one explicitly designs a system to convolve a signal by a predefined impulse response (for example when building a digital filter); but more often than not, convolution is used to *model* various physical processes involved in a system. These physical processes can be transmission delays or dispersions, the limited bandwidth of an amplifier, transmission medium or electro-mechanical system, the explicit use of passive R, L, C network to achieve some filtering, etc... Thus, it might not be out of place to find convolution used in the description of some elements of a telephone system, but it's a modeling tool, not an actual process.

Here is an analogy: the trajectory of a cannonball is a parabola, but it makes little sense to ask which mechanical device in a cannon is responsible for computing $y = ax^2 + b$.

Comment: +1 i see. can you recommend any reading material for understanding how analog circuit in a classic telephone transforms the signal before it transmits it over the wires?

Comment: @magnetar: What pichenettes is talking about would probably be referred to as "signals and systems" theory, and would be a common topic for second- or third-year undergraduate study in electrical engineering. In engineering, most everything is *just a model* for what goes on in the real world. It is convenient and "close enough" to model many processes as linear systems (such as the RLC networks mentioned above). When you apply an input to a linear system, the system output can be calculated by convolving the system's impulse response with the input signal.

Comment: @pichenettes: I like the cannonball analogy, BTW.

Comment: For some further reading material, [here is a link](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-003-signals-and-systems-spring-2010/) to materials for a signals and systems course offered by [MIT OpenCourseWare](http://http://ocw.mit.edu). I haven't read through it, but for the price, it might be worth a look.

Comment: And the OCW Oppenheim Signals and Systems lectures (which I don't think are linked from other page): http://ocw.mit.edu/resources/res-6-007-signals-and-systems-spring-2011/video-lectures/

Answer (score -1):

In a conventional 20th Century telephone, the "transmitter" (microphone) consisted of a small vial containing graphite powder, with two electrical contacts poking through the otherwise insulated vial wall.  Vibrations from sound would push the graphite particles closer together or pull them farther apart, creating a variable resistance (as "seen" between the two contacts).  Applying a voltage to the receiver would thus result in a variable current that was the "signal".

Comment: How is this an answer to what was asked?

Comment: @DilipSarwate -- It's what makes it possible to transmit sound over a wire, which is what the OP asked.  I could go into a few more details, if that seems merited.  Keep in mind that there were no "active" components in the conventional telephone, or anywhere in the conventional phone network, once two lines were connected together.

Comment: (Actually that last statement was not entirely accurate.  "Active" in EE parlance, basically means capable of having positive gain, and the "transmitter" had positive gain -- the only component in the circuit with positive gain, and hence quite critical to the whole setup.)